# How can I read PostgreSQL arrays with SOCI?

Tags: postgresql, soci

I need to execute some query that returns (SELECTs) a [PostgreSQL array](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html), but the [documentation of SOCI's PostgreSQL backend](http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/backends/postgresql.html) doesn't mention anything about arrays.

If I just try to put it into a `soci::rowset`, it thinks that it is a string column and returns a string like `"{1, 2, 3}"` which I would hate to parse. Is there any way to get SOCI to handle that data type automatically, either with `soci::into` or via a `soci::rowset`? Or do I have to resort to JOINing with the array in order to get separate rows in the resultset?

I'm using SOCI 3.2 and PostgreSQL 9.3.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I face the same issue... Thx

Comment: I didn't find a good solution. In case the array size is constant and known, we resort to something like `SELECT arr[1], arr[2], arr[3] FROM table`. In other cases we JOIN with the array.